# Чем (в данном случае) можно заменить слова «не ходил» (общественный транспорт)?

Tags: стилистика

В город Бима добрался под вечер: общественный транспорт уже
не ходил, лишь таксисты предлагали свои услуги. («Не ходил» – звучит некрасиво, а «не функционировал» - слишком официально. Отсутствовал, не работал – тоже плохо)

Comment: Скорее, в тексте такого жанра лишнее слово - "общественный", оно больше подходит для новостей и отчётов. "Не ходил" - лучший вариант из всего возможного.

Comment: Могу и "общественный" заменить. Было бы чем.

Comment: Можно вообще без него. Под просто "транспортом" в городе обычно подразумевают тот, который формально называют "общественным".

Comment: Далее описано, как, за неимением общественного транспорта, я вынужден был ехать на мототакси (есть такой вид транспорта в странах третьего мира). Это ведь тоже транспорт, получается нелепо.

Comment: Назовите его "городским" (за отсутствием городского транспорта, который к тому времени уже не ходил), это более демократичное название "общественного".

Comment: Не согласен. Общественный - это именно общественный, который ходит по установленным маршрутам. А городской - это включая такси и мусороуборщики.

Comment: "Городским" я не могу его назвать. Это был общественный транспорт, скорее пригородного направления. В данном контексте.

Comment: Извините, ответил в тексте основного ответа . Ваш вопрос в комментариях к моему ответу пришлось удалить вместе с самим моим ответом.

Comment: "Автобусы уже не ходили" ? Какой ещё там может быть транспорт, не метро же.

Comment: На индонезийском острове Сумбава метро пока не построили. Трамваев там тоже нет. Но это уже не важно: я уже сам переделал саой текст.

Answer (score 1):

"общественный транспорт уже не ходил" - корректная фраза нейтрального стиля, не разговорная.

Слово транспорт употреблено в значении "Тот или иной вид перевозочных средств" . Городской транспорт - автобусы, трамваи и пр. А они именно ходят.

А вот транспорт как отрасль народного хозяйства, обслуживающая различные виды перевозок, работает,функционирует, развивается,  не "ходит". Может быть, Вас это смутило?

По-моему, ничего не нужно менять, всё на месте.

Comment: Оцените исправленный вариант. В город Бима добрался под вечер - с общественным транспортом опоздал: лишь таксисты предлагали свои услуги.

Comment: Ваш первый вариант яснее. Почему "с общественным транспортом"? опоздал с чем? Или всё-таки "добрался (чем?)общественным транспортом" ? Двоеточие как объяснить? Опоздал (почему?), потому что лишь таксисты предлагали услуги? По-моему, вполне достаточно запятой, а вот после "под вечер" двоеточие было на месте. Честно говоря, первый вариант, когда записываешь фразы, непроизвольно появляющиеся в мозгу, чаще бывает лучше, чем исправленные(если нет ошибок, конечно)

Comment: Не знаю как Виктора, но меня "смутило" именно это. *"А вот транспорт как отрасль народного хозяйства"* Не то чтобы смутило, но возникло стойкое ощущение, что "транспорт" здесь скорее всего поймут неправильно. Не как отдельные автобусы-троллейбусы-трамваи, а как инфраструктуру в целом. *"Железная дорога уже не ходила"*. Транспорт не ходит, если это не отдельная транспортная единица, а вот **работать** может. Флот не плавает (и не ходит). Телевидение не показывает. Поголовье не доится. Плавают, показывают и доятся суда, телевизоры и коровы. Так и тут.

Comment: Не знаю,кто может так понять. В основном люди как раз и используют слово транспорт в значении "перевозочное средство". Посмотрела по сайтам. Вот на юридическом форуме «Автоюрист» 
 http://yurprava.ru/novoe-v-rossijskom-zakonodatelstve/dvizhenie-po-polose-dlya-obshhestvennogo-transporta-skoro-razreshat/ , вот на форуме чисто бытовом: А кто-нибудь подскажет, до которого часа ходит общественный транспорт из Дзержинска до Нижнего Новгорода?

Comment: Вот в газете: "Комсомольская Правда" :В связи с массовыми мероприятиями, которые проходят сегодня на площади Великого Национального собрания, общественный транспорт уже не ходит по бульвару Штефана чел Маре. Это первые попавшиеся, в других тоже, есть на новостных сайтах, и везде "транспорт не ходит", и все понимают правильно, что не ходят автобусы и троллейбусы.

Answer (score 0):

> > «Не ходил» – звучит некрасиво

Вполне нормально звучит.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/7793)

Comment: У вас зато блестящий ответ: "не работал". "Транспорт не работал" – это гораздо лучше, чем "не ходил". Привет стилисту.

Comment: "Зато" - не принимается. Если Вам не нравится мой ответ, можете попытаться сформулировать корректно, без "зато". Иначе это детский сад "Марьиванна, он первый начал".

Comment: Оцените исправленный вариант. В город Бима добрался под вечер - с общественным транспортом опоздал: лишь таксисты предлагали свои услуги.

Comment: Добились? И так буду поступать и впредь с каждой вашей выходкой, пока не научитесь вести разговор корректно.

Comment: Молодца! Я прям не знаю, что делать... Но все же скажу: вы редкостная базарная баба, behemothus. Без обид, сами напросились. ))

Answer (score 0):

В город Бима добрался под вечер, к превеликой радости таксистов опоздав на последний автобус. Но их надежды не оправдались. Сколько километров до аэропорта? Не меньше десяти…? «Что ж, до утра дойду…» – подумал, и зашагал вперед по освещенной фонарями ночной трассе.

Comment: Ответил в тексте.

Answer (score 0):

Заменить можно на "не работал". Или всю фразу переделать.

Вопрос, нужно ли менять, для Вас не стоит (а то получится как с "добродетелем" - непонятно, в чем вопрос)?

Я согласен, что в сочетании с "общественным транспортом" не ходил немного режет слух своей разговорностью, а "не функционировал"- это слишком деловой стиль, но тут непонятно, а какой стиль вообще Вы (или герой) тут исповедуете?

@Виктор,

> Это - путевые заметки. То есть, документально описанное путешествие с
>   небольшими вставками всяческой отсебятины. За неформальный стиль меня
>   не расстреляют, но "разговорный" нежелателен.

Тогда попробуйте "не работал". Или уже переделать всю фразу. Потому, что общественный транспорт ночью именно не работает.

> Оцените исправленный вариант
>
> В город Бима добрался под вечер - с общественным транспортом опоздал:
>   лишь таксисты предлагали свои услуги

Я улучшений не вижу, вы сбиваетесь на еще более разговорный вариант. Но повторяю, у меня единственная претензия по "общественному транспорту" в сочетании с "ходит". По контексту мне нравится "не работал". Сочетание работа общественного транспорта можно найти на любом заборе, в то время как "транспорт ходит" это примерно как если бы "ходила" железная дорога. Я думаю, вы не в том направлении ищете.

Answer (score 0):

не идеал, конечно, но как один из вариантов - "курсировал"